# How to backup steam downloads?

Tags: steam

Recently I have installed some games from steam. The size of those games may be about 50GB. I install fresh copy Ubuntu frequently. But that will delete all the games that I downloaded. So, I was thinking if there is any way of backing up those downloads without breaking any laws.

Comment: Why would you frequently install a fresh copy of Linux? Plenty people have never reinstalled Ubuntu since many previous versions, always just upgrade when a new release comes out! There's really no need for it :)

Comment: A new install feels fresher to me :) But, I will try upgrading next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
right click on your game
set "properties">local files> "backup game files"

but... you cannot worry about lost your games... They still your games and they are stored in the cloud . 
You can download again your games (it is yours).
And the same holds for its SAVEGAMES , 98% of games of steam has backup online of your savegames.

ONLY ONE THINK...
DON'T LOSE YOUR LOGIN AND PASSWORD...

Only that...